# How to prevent Windows stopping my vb.net (framework 4) when taking a very, very long time to process a function

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0

I have an old vb.net Winform framework 4 application that I have to maintain.
This application is calling a function on a server which take about 20 minutes to complete.
The problem is that after about 15 minutes, Windows thinks the program is frozen and show the message "This program has stopped working" and it's closing the program.
I tried to play with threading, tasks, async, but I can't find a solution to this issue.
Is there a way to prevent Windows doing that?

Comment: Putting the call to the server in a [BackgroundWorker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker) should work for that. It means that Windows can still keep prodding the Form to check it is still operating, while the BGW is waiting.

Comment: I did that and it works! Thanks!